# Link button in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How can I make Button to look like LinkButton, and I don't want to use 
Hyperlink...!!

Any suggestions

Comment: If anyone cares, the issue with all the answers in here is that the links in the answers don't actually behave like links.  They are not aware of the visited url history and the colors aren't the system url colors.  But, if you don't have those requirements, they're okay.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use the correct Windows colors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094447

Answer (score 157, accepted):

If you don't want any of the normal Button style and just want something that looks like a hyperlink you could start with this

```
<Button Margin="5" Content="Test" Cursor="Hand">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </TextBlock>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Here's the same as a style:

```
<Style
    x:Key="LinkButton"
    TargetType="Button">
    <Setter
        Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="Button">
                <TextBlock
                    TextDecorations="Underline">
                <ContentPresenter /></TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter
        Property="Foreground"
        Value="Blue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger
            Property="IsMouseOver"
            Value="true">
            <Setter
                Property="Foreground"
                Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and you can use it like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Content="Clicky" />
```

Comment: Please note that there's a typo here - LinkButon

Comment: This answer produces a button which has a space between the underline and the text.  @Christians answer resolves this.

Comment: This also does not have the "hand" pointer when hovering over the hyperlink. Use the community wiki answer for this functionality.

Comment: I suggest to add `<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"><Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" /> </Trigger>` to handle IsEnabled state

Answer (score 36):

```
<Style x:Key="LinkButton" 
       TargetType="Button"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Button}}"
       >

    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding  ContentTemplate}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  >
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                        </Style>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

MichaC's and Anderson's version placed the underline slightly wrong, here is an updated version that will just add an underline to any `TextBlock` that are inside the `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: Christian: How comes I can't see any underline using your style? MichaC's just worked fine for me.

Comment: This isn't working for me either.  The style within ContentPresenter.Resources just isn't getting applied to any TextBlock within the Button

Comment: OK, the issue seems to be that the style only applies to an implicitly generated TextBlock

Comment: <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}">Text</Button>    works

Comment: <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"> <TextBlock Text="test"/></Button> does not work

Comment: Asking this as a separate question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628101/how-do-i-correctly-apply-a-style-to-content-presenter

Comment: Perfect. I'd make one tiny addition to the style triggers to show a gray textblock if the button is disabled. `<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
    </Trigger>`

Comment: Is there someone who knows if it is possible to inject/add a ContextMenu to a button styled with Christian's solution?

Answer (score 30):

Here's MichaC's suggestion implemented as a `Style` that you can reuse on any button:

```
<Style x:Key="LinkButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Made this a community wiki, considering 99% of this answer is stolen from MichaC :)

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way (I do this in my application):

```
<TextBlock Name="..."
   Text="..."
   Cursor="Hand"
   Foreground="Blue"
   TextDecorations="Underline"
   MouseLeftButtonUp=..."
/>
```

you have full control on TextDecoration, e.g. change pen style or offset.
take a look at this link to find out more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecorations.underline.aspx

Comment: Bad Practice, Styling a Link button as suggested is Far better...
what if you have 50 LinkButtons like that?  Additionally, what about if you need to add a Hover action or maybe a different decoration?

Comment: I disagree with Tomer.  "bad practise" implies there's never a need for this simpler approach.  I have a case right now where this was the perfect solution i.e. was creating button in code-behind).  Thanks Siavash.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a bad practice. It will be perfect for some scenarios.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution using `Hyperlink` is to put in inside `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Click="...">
        <TextBlock Text="Link text" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not want to use Hyperlink?

```
<Button>
    <Hyperlink>
</Button>
```

Comment: Coz, Whenever I try to get parent in Visual tree it throws an Exception saying Hyperlink is not visual or Visual3d

Comment: I want to use this. I got it working but I can't seem to get rid of the shadow on the edges of the button. How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Combination of all proposed solutions:
Completed style, as in the accepted version, but without hardcoded values.

```xml
<Style
    x:Key="HyperlinkButton"
    TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
    >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <TextBlock>
                    <Hyperlink
                        Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
                        CommandTarget="{TemplateBinding CommandTarget}"
                        CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}"
                        >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```