# How do I use the correct Windows system colors?

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, styles

I want to use XAML to style a WPF button to look like the "Mixer" and "Change date and time settings..." text of these Windows 7 Notification area flyouts.

Does a property of [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms603159.aspx) define that color? Which?

```
<Setter Property="Foreground"
        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.????}}" />
```

[image: Windows 7 Notification area flyout]

Comment: The SystemColors class works for me. You can bind to it like this: {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}. Is there anything specific that's not working for you?

Comment: It works. I just need to know how to choose the correct color. "HighlightBrushKey" is close, but not quite the right shade of blue.

Comment: You may want to read the [Aero Theme aesthetics guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742484).

Comment: From experimentation, it seems to be HotTrack. Both are #0066CC on my system. I wish there was a better way to figure this out and to know for sure. MSDN describes it as "the color used to designate a hot-tracked item". Thanks, Microsoft!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The best method I've found is experimentation and guessing.

I created a little utility to visualize these colors.

### Interface

[image: System.Windows.SystemColors]

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SystemColors1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="System.Windows.SystemColors" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CellColor">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}" />
                    </TextBlock.Background>
                    <TextBlock.Text> 
                        &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                        &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                        &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                  Name="SystemColorsList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellColor}"
                                    Header="Color"
                                    Width="Auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                    Header="Name"
                                    Width="Auto"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### C#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SystemColors1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<ColorAndName> l = new List<ColorAndName>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo i in typeof(System.Windows.SystemColors).GetProperties())
            {
                if (i.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
                {
                    ColorAndName cn = new ColorAndName();
                    cn.Color = (Color)i.GetValue(new Color(), BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null);
                    cn.Name = i.Name;
                    l.Add(cn);
                }
            }

            SystemColorsList.DataContext = l;
        }
    }

    class ColorAndName
    {
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good list, thanks. For others who struggled getting the colours to appear (like me!) it's important to add 'Key' to the end of the names as they are listed here. E.g. {DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextColorKey}}

Answer (score 7):

Check out this [SystemColors reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20111110203549/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx), and specifically the [Aero Theme colors](https://web.archive.org/web/20130203125445/http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-38-64-SystemColors+Reference/5582.swatch_5F00_Aero.png).

It's not obvious which color name that text would use, but trying to eyeball it, it looks like `HighlightBrush` or `MenuHighlightBrush` could be candidates...

Comment: From experimentation, it seems to be HotTrack.

Comment: Both links are dead

Comment: @Lennart Thanks! Updated the post with Wayback Machine links (where would the web be without the Wayback Machine?)

Comment: @DanJ Appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's very hard to compare colours by eye!

If you take a screen shot (Prt Scr button on your keyboard) you can then paste it into mspaint and use the eye dropper to get the actual colour values.

Tricky on the aliased text, but I read the colour of the text in the screenshot to be R,G,B=0,102,204 and HotTrackColor to be R,G,B = 0,102,203

As I say, the difference could be due to the aliasing on the text.

Note:
After clicking with the Eye Dropper Tool you might need to cilck "Edit colours" to see the actual colour values. You do in win7 anyway.