# How Do I Correctly Apply a Style to Content Presenter

Tags: wpf, styles

I'm working with this answer to this question about link buttons:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3564706/945

The problem is that the TextDecoration Underline style is only being applied to autogenerated TextBlocks.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}">Text</Button>
```

'Text' is underlined

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"><TextBlock Text='Text' /></Button>
```

'Text' is not underlined

Why is it not applying to any TextBlock within the content?

This is the relevant portion of the style:

```
<Style x:Key="LinkButton" 
       TargetType="Button"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Button}}"
       >

    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding  ContentTemplate}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  >
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                        </Style>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Why are you putting a TextBlock inside a Button? The Button class has its own built-in "Content" field which will format and scale nicely-- you can also edit the way it does so easily in Blend.

`<Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Content="Text" />`

Answer (score 5):

I belive that when you put a Framework element inside a ContentControl, the Template is not applied. If you also declare your TextBlock style as a Button's resource, it works in both cases.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LinkButton"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Button}}"
           TargetType="Button">

        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" >
                        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                            </Style>
                        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}">Text</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="Text" />
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: But the whole point is to define a single "LinkButton" style once.  Not apply a custom style to every single link button in the application

Comment: You can define the complete style in your control resources (or choose the style in the Button's resources as the principal) and define the style in the ContententPresenter as a placeholder based on the principal.

Answer (score 2):

I met with simular trouble yesterday. You can move style setters for text block up, out of Template node, so your styles won't erase after you change content of control.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set `x:Key="LinkButton"`. Implicit styles will not work if you set the key. Remove the key and it will be applied to all the buttons